# how to write the list of array values to the text file (list of file names)

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of values(file names) in two variables now i need to write the 2 set of file names to the individual files.

But here code part write to text file `C1.ForEach(r => sw.WriteLine(r));` will not write the values file is empty.

```
//Split the Files
var Alternated = Files
                .Select((name, index) => new { name, index })
                .GroupBy(item => item.index % 2, item => item.name)
                .Select(group => group.ToList())
                .ToArray();

//Assigning alternate files to the variable  
var C1 = Alternated[0];
var C2 = Alternated[1];

// Check if file already exists. If yes, delete it.   
string filepath = FilePath; 
string filepath2 = FilePath2; 
if (File.Exists(filepath) || File.Exists(filepath2))
{
    File.Delete(filepath);
    File.Delete(filepath2);
}
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filepath))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    C1.ForEach(r => sw.WriteLine(r));

}
using (FileStream fs1 = File.Create(filepath1))
{
    StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);
    C2.ForEach(r => sw.WriteLine(r));

}
```

Comment: Ok. Do you have an issue?

Comment: might be a typo, to define filepath2 and use filepath1

Comment: can you build this code without error? cause there are many typos

Comment: Dispose the StreamWriters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filepath1)) 
{
}
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filepath2)) 
{
}
using (StreamWriter wrt = new StreamWriter(filepath1, true))
{
    Container1.ForEach(r => wrt.WriteLine(r));
}
using (StreamWriter wrt = new StreamWriter(filepath2, true))
{
    Container2.ForEach(r => wrt.WriteLine(r));
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: You should add some explanation to help other people understand that what you mean @Dinesh kumar Mohan

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the stream. This would clear the buffers for current writer and ensures any duffered data to be written to the underlying stream. You could do so by using `StreamWriter.Flush`.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filepath1))
{
    StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);
    C2.ForEach(r => sw1.WriteLine(r));
    sw1.Flush();
}
```

Or by making use of the `using` block which ensures the same before the object is disposed.

```
using (FileStream fs1 = File.Create(filepath2))
{
    using(StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(fs1))
    {
        C2.ForEach(r => sw1.WriteLine(r));
    }
}
```